# FloatingActionButton not floating over BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android-studio

I followed the most voted answer and added `app:layout_insetEdge="bottom"` in coordinatelayout and bottomnavigationview. This did not work. My Floating button is ABOVE bottomnavigationview and is floating over VIEWPAGER.

if i set it to top center it will float over appbar.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    app:layout_insetEdge="bottom">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foreground="@mipmap/ic_banner_foreground">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/top_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#00FF82"
            app:tabMinWidth="97.99dp"
            app:tabMode="auto"
            app:tabTextColor="#FFFFFF" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_insetEdge="bottom"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_bar"/>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="582dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="582dp" />
    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/post_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_eco_24"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"/>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: how is the preview of the goal?

Comment: On the right it looks fine, on the left it does not. When i run the app, it does not look alright as well.

Comment: hmm, do you have the design of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @ErwinKurniawanA I just need the floating button to float over bottomnavview, and to fit there.

Comment: I added it under BottomNavigationBar and it worked but it does not detect it as an item in the bar hence some icons are obscured.